# R - The cumulative number of cases by days since confirmed cases

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to draw the cumulative number of cases in the remaining days on the line chart, assuming the day when the number of cases reaches 100,000 for the 10 countries I selected. I'm extracting the data for the next dates when the number of cases reaches 100,000, but I don't know how to get the days I need to put on the x-axis.
Here is the original question: "c)  Draw line graph for the cumulative number of cases by days since 100000th confirmed case"

I could write the code below:

```
    library(utils)
COVID_data <-read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

    confirmed_COVID_data <- COVID_data %>% 
  filter(countriesAndTerritories %in% ten_countries) %>%
  filter(cases >0) %>% 
  mutate(dateRep = as.Date(dateRep, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>%
  arrange(dateRep) %>%
  mutate(cum_cases = cumsum(cases)) %>%
  filter(cum_cases >= 100000)
```

I tried to use the below code in order to assign day numbers for confirmed cases, but the problem is the numbers are in order for all countries. I need days for each country.

```
confirmed_COVID_data <- tibble::rowid_to_column(confirmed_COVID_data, "confirmed_days")
```

How can find days for each country? Could you help me?

Comment: I added a solution below, but really you just need to add `%>% 
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_days = row_number())` to the end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
confirmed_COVID_data <- COVID_data %>% 
  filter(countriesAndTerritories %in% ten_countries) %>%
  filter(cases >0) %>% 
  mutate(dateRep = as.Date(dateRep, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>%
  arrange(dateRep) %>%
  mutate(cum_cases = cumsum(cases)) %>%
  filter(cum_cases >= 100000) %>% 
  group_by(countriesAndTerritories) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_days = row_number())
```

This will give us `cumulative_days` for each country:

```
# Groups:   countriesAndTerritories [6]
  dateRep      day month  year   cases deaths countriesAndTerritor~ geoId countryterritoryC~ popData2020 continentExp cum_cases cumulative_days
  <date>     <int> <int> <int>   <int>  <int> <chr>                 <chr> <chr>                    <int> <chr>            <int>           <int>
1 2021-03-01     1     3  2021  456112   8414 Austria               AT    AUT                    8901064 Europe          456112               1
2 2021-03-01     1     3  2021  779096  22278 Belgium               BE    BEL                   11522440 Europe          779096               1
3 2021-03-01     1     3  2021  247038  10191 Bulgaria              BG    BGR                    6951482 Europe          247038               1
4 2021-03-01     1     3  2021  242973   5526 Croatia               HR    HRV                    4058165 Europe          242973               1
5 2021-03-01     1     3  2021 1240051  20469 Czechia               CZ    CZE                   10693939 Europe         1240051               1
6 2021-03-01     1     3  2021  211195   2361 Denmark               DK    DNK                    5822763 Europe          211195               1
```